# I have used WaitForSingleObject in C++ and its return value is "WAIT_OBJECT_0" all the time

Tags: c++, serial-port

The function `WaitForSingleObject` returns `timeout flag("WAIT_OBJECT_0")` in all cases.

Only for testing I have commented this line

```
(while((WaitForSingleObject(ovread.hEvent,timeout)==WAIT_OBJECT_0)))
```

and the comport responds as expected.
I have tried various timeouts including INFINITE.
Can someone tell me where the error could be occurring.

```
int timeout=500;
OVERLAPPED ovread;
memset(&ovread, 0, sizeof(ovread));
ovread.hEvent = CreateEvent( 0,true,0,0);
while((WaitForSingleObject(ovread.hEvent,timeout)==WAIT_OBJECT_0))
{
 //Execute the following code
 ReadFile(h,buf,sizeof(buf),&read,&ovread);
}
```

Comment: Why do you make your event manual reset (passing `true` for the [second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx))?

Comment: In the code shown, it is impossible for `WaitForSingleObject()` to return `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, because the code is calling `CreateEvent()` with `bInitialState=FALSE` and is not doing anything that signals the event to satisfy the wait.

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? It has no comments and its intended function is not described.

Answer (score 0):

The reading logic should more or less use the following code flow:

```
int timeout = 500;
OVERLAPPED ovread = {0}
ovread.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

if (ovread.hEvent == NULL) {
   // Error creating overlapped event; abort.
   return FALSE;
}

if (!ReadFile(h, buf, sizeof(buf), &read, &ovread)) {
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
        // Handle error in communications
    }
    else {
        DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(ovread.hEvent,timeout); 

        switch (ret) {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                HandleASuccessfulRead(buf, read);
                break;
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                // Handle timeout
                break;
            case WAIT_FAILED:
                // Handle failure
                break;
            default:
                // what else to handle?
                break;
        }
    }
}
else {    
    // read completed immediately
    HandleASuccessfulRead(buf, read);
}
```